# What's wrong with DCOM?

Tags: dcom

There seems to be a lot of enmity against DCOM, and I'm curious to understand why. For a company still writing to the Win32 SKD using C++, is there any real reason not to use DCOM in current or future development? Is some future version of Windows not going to support it? Is it too fragile and fails to work often? Is it too complicated to implement compared to other technologies? What's the deal?

Comment: everything ;) (Just kidding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, DCOM is a distributed version of COM and COM is very complex by itself and it's very easy to do something wrong unintentionally (see [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824397/why-would-i-use-both-com-threading-model-instead-of-free) and the answer to it for examples). With DCOM you just have even more ways to hurt yourself.

Other than that it works and is for example a good way for hosting in-proc COM components in a separated process.

Comment: I actually find COM to be quite understandable and rather simplistic if you understand pointers and reference counters.

Comment: Believe me, IUnknown member functions are just the beginning. Then come apartments, concurrency and other stuff that can cause horrible pain.

Comment: Then what would you recommended for a local win32 SDK only service and client app that need to communicate? Yes DCOM is complicated, but what technology filling these requirements isn't?

Comment: If you have two processes using RPC directly can often be easier and more reliable. But then you will not have "objects" - you will have to maintain state on the server manually.

Answer (score 7):

1. Security model. Especially when computers are not in the same domain (or aren't in domain at all).
2. Auto interfaces modeled for Visual Basic (original, not .NET), obsolete and not pretty to use from other languages.

If you only want to develop in C++ and deploy in controlled network, it may still be a good choice.

Comment: The security issues across local-OS boundaries (anything on another machine) can't be emphasized enough. "Managing" DCOM security is utterly impossible. (And good luck trying to track down errors or interpreting error messages.)

Answer (score 5):

I dislike COM/DCOM because `"Catastrophic failure"` is the most unhelpful error message in the history of error messages.

Comment: That would be the "feel-good" message for the user.  This way they know they are doing it right.

Comment: ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS to sum it up.

Answer (score 2):

If your trying to build a client server application and want the communication to go across network boundaries (for example the internet) then DCOM can be problematic due to firewalls.

I had worked on a very success server application which was distributed using DCOM, we let the system handle most of the complexity by creating COM+ Server Applications and exporting Application Proxies. In this case it worked very well as long as all of our versions were synched up.

Comment: I forgot to mention our client and server would be local to the same machine, both written by us and deployed together, so no network or synchronization problems.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a large system using DCOM in the late 90's. Although it worked pretty well, there were a couple of issues. For starters it uses unpredictable port numbers for communication. It is not scalable, and you are much better off using WCF than DCOM.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are confined to the Win32 SDK - no .NET allowed. I know, I know, but I don't make the rules

Comment: Still I believe you could use web services - I'm pretty sure there are SOAP packages for C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think momentum has shifted to SOAP and other web service technology because it is:

- easier to deploy systems in the presence of firewalls
- no vendor lock-in

I've never used DCOM myself, so I can't really comment on its general quality or fitness.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned my use would be for local DCOM - both client and server on the same machine. Converting everything to ASCII and then wrapping that with more ASCII tags then parsing the ASCII result is extremely ineficient.

Comment: Ah, I hear you. And yes, SOAP is got its own problems.